# 550 permanent failure when sending email to SMS number with smtplib

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

When using the smtplib library to send emails to phone numbers (ex. number@tmomail.net), my email gets blocked with the message 550 permanent failure for one or more recipients.

I can successfully send emails using the smtplib library to normal emails. I have used my script to send emails to my personal email.

I can also send emails to the phone number successfully using the manual gmail client. If I log into google manually, fill out the form, the email sends to the number perfectly fine.

```
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.login(self.email, self.password)
        subject = 'test'
        body = 'hello world'
        msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
        smtp.sendmail(self.email, validNumber@carrier.com, msg)
```

Can someone tell me how to make the text go through unblocked the same way it does when it emails normal gmails?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is specific to T-Mobile numbers. Refer to the answer here:

https://support.t-mobile.com/thread/116618

> "T-Mobile is now blocking traffic where the sending Domain is altered from the true sending address: IE support@customerservice.com, when the domain is actually is support@gmail.com. senders will receive a 550 bounceback error . To correct this issue, Senders will need to revert their sending address to their actual email address."